# How to calculate the tax free amount of sales, based on date fields?

Tags: sql-server

i need your help for a task that i have undertaken and i face difficulties.

So, i have to calculate the NET amount of sales for some products, which were sold in different cities on different years and for this reason different tax rate is applied.

Specifically, i have a dimension table (Dim_Cities) which consists of the cities that the products can be sold.

i.e
Dim_Cities:

```
CityID, CityName, Area, District.
```

Dim_Cities:

```
1, "Athens", "Attiki", "Central Greece".
```

Also, i have a file/table which consists of the following information :

i.e

```
[SalesArea]
,[EffectiveFrom_2019]
,[EffectiveTo_2019]
,[VAT_2019]


,[EffectiveFrom_2018]
,[EffectiveTo_2018]
,[VAT_2018]


,[EffectiveFrom_2017]
,[EffectiveTo_2017]
,[VAT_2017]


,[EffectiveFrom_2016_Semester1]
,[EffectiveTo_2016_Semester1]
,[VAT_2016_Semester1]


,[EffectiveFrom_2016_Semester2]
,[EffectiveTo_2016_Semester2]
,[VAT_2016_Semester2]
```

i.e

```
"Athens", "2019-01-01", "2019-12-31", 0.24,

"2018-01-01", "2018-12-31", 0.24,

"2017-01-01", "2017-12-31", 0.17,

"2016-01-01", "2016-05-31", 0.16,

"2016-01-06", "2016-12-31", 0.24
```

And of course there is a fact table that holds all the information,

i.e

```
 FactSales_ID,  CityID, SaleAmount (with VAT), SaleDate_ID.
```

The question is how to compute for every city the "TAX-Free SalesAmount", that corresponds to each particular saledate? In other words, i think that i have to create a function that computes every time the NET amount, substracting in each case the corresponding tax rate, based on the date and city that it finds. Can anyone help me or guide me to achieve this please?

Comment: Seems you need to normalise your design. You shouldn't have a separate column for each year, you should have a column, for the year (and semester, it seems).

Comment: You can encourage others to examine your issue by posting a script / fiddle that contains consumable data. Note that over-trivializing your sample data is not helpful. You have a single city - is city even relevant here for anything other than grouping? I.e, does the rate vary by city and period? Are we to guess at what values SaleDate_ID contains?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are asking how to query your data to produce this result or how to design your data warehouse to make this data available - but I'm hoping you are asking about how to design your data warehouse as this information should definitely be pre-calculated and held in your DW rather than being calculated every time anyone wants to report on the data.

One of the key points of building a DW is that all the complex business logic should be handled in the ETL (as much as possible) so that the actually reporting is simple; the only calculations in a reporting process are those that can't be pre-calculated.

If your CITY Dim is SCD2 (or could be made to be SCD2) then I would add the VAT rate as an attribute to that Dim - otherwise you could hold VAT Rate in a "worker" table.

When your ETL loads your Fact table you would use the VAT rate on the CITY Dim (or in the worker table) to calculate the Net and Gross amounts and hold both as measures in your fact table